# Ember Simple Auth Logout Action with Django Backend

Tags: django, authentication, ember.js

I'm using ember simple-auth library with ember simple-auth-token.
However, every time I perform a logout action, django does not delete the token of the logged in user.

I should point out that the frontend works like a charm!

I am wondering if there should be a change in the frontend or in the backend code.

The invalidate() method should normally take care of the token refresh action, right?.

Here is my code, which is pretty much the same as the code presented in the README of ember simple auth.

**controller/application.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    session: Ember.inject.service('session'),

        actions: {
            invalidateSession() {
                this.get('session').invalidate();
            }
        }
 });
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ember-simple-auth-token's authenticators don't implement the `invalidate` method that called upon session invalidation and can be used to send a request to the backend to invalidate the token. Without that method being implemented Ember Simple Auth simply deletes the token on the client side.

You should be able to extend the ember-simple-auth-token authenticator you're using and implement the `invalidate` method so that it sends a token invalidation request to the backend. Be sure to return a promise though.